# Magento - Hide products that use placeholder on category page

Tags: php, magento

I have added the following code, which seems to "hide" the products using the placeholder. 
How can i make it so it completely skips that product.

The reason is on the grid of 50. Only 3 have images on the main page. Then only 3 will show and make the user go to the next page to see more.

```
 <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $small_image = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>
        <?php if(!strpos($small_image,'placeholder/small_image')){ ?>
```